# Allow custom non-AD CRM users with SharePoint online login

Tags: sharepoint-online, adfs, sync, ad, azure-ad

Trying to figure-out if it's possible to allow for **non-AD users from a custom CRM system** (where users credentials are stored in a custom SQLServer DB) to login with their credentials on SharePoint online!?, without creating a new credentials for O365 or even on the customer AD domain.

Was looking at "**Azure AD Connec**t", but not sure if it's would be a good fit!!.

Is it even possible to have a proper sync. with non-Active directory users for SharePoint online?, what are the alternatives if any?.

Comment: Sync only works with AD either On Prem or Cloud. SP online does allow you to open collaboration to users outside of your organisation and you can do that via sharing. https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Share-sites-or-documents-with-people-outside-your-organization-80e49744-e30f-44db-8d51-16661b1d4232

Comment: Thanks, As I understand that I can have sharing for SP online can be only for Office 365 accounts, Microsoft or windows live accounts, and only guest "anonymous" accounts for documents sharing not sites or libraries.  Which doesn't give a way to have custom non-Ad users login as if they have O365 accounts!.  I read that **MIM ( Microsoft Identity Manager )** can sync non-AD users to allow them logging-in on SP online, not sure how, or should be configured !?, any help around this please.